# How to show image in header while pdf/print from webpage using phantomjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs

I am new to phantomjs. Installed phantomjs 1.9.7.

I'm generating pdf files using phantomjs(example: printheaderfooter.js) but I would like to repeat a defined header with HTML, it works when there are no images but as soon I add it doesn't work.

Is there any way to show image in header?

Comment: are you passing option `--load-images=yes` ?

Comment: No, where to add this option? I am running phantomjs command from rails controller.

Comment: when you run phantomjs from command, you have to pass this option. Although default value is `yes` but give a try. Do `phantomjs --help` for more

Comment: No result I have passed --load-images=yes in command. I have pass header
 contents: function(pageNum, numPages) { return "<img src='https://www.google.com.bo/images/srpr/logo4w.png' height='0.95cm'/>" + pageNum + "/" + numPages; }